# Foreground App detection of Firefox OS

Tags: firefox-os, dumpsys

In Android, we can use "dumpsys activity top" to obtain the Foreground App information.
But in Firefox OS, the dumpsys command not provide the Foreground App information.
Dose their have any way to detect which Foreground App are running?

Comment: Does dumpsys work at all in Firefox? If so, are you sure the name of the package isn't anywhere in there?